# MySQL unique record selection approach

Tags: php, mysql, unique

i have a huge product table, this is its simplified structure:

```
ID|SHOP|...|MPN|PRICE|CLICKS
```

i can have the same product coming from different shops, every shop have its own product ID, but (if the shop support it) the MPN for same products is the same.

when i query the database for products, order them by clicks, and if there is the same product from multiple source it is showed twice.

Since im ordered by clicks, the two "equal products" can be far from each other, so its quiete intensive to elaborate it at runtime (consider also the result are paginated and the two equals could be in differente pages).

i was thinking about a query that (if there are multiple result of the same mpn) duplicate some columns as needed (but them how my software can know about the dynamically created columns), i was thinking about SELF JOIN but i don't know how many shop can carry the same product (maybe i can assume all the shop i use...)

My main problem is in search (or category) result where i have a list of products with the "BUY AT SHOP FOR PRICE" button that redirect to the shop... my goal is to have more button to BUY if the product (equal by MPN) have duplicate.

I can keep clicks aligned for both product when a user click on the buy button and maybe it would help

Product detail page is not a big deal, since i have a single product i can get all other instances of it by MPN and it is quiete easy

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62545805/edit) , include a few data example, at least one query you've attempted so far and your expected output. It's better (and shorter in the question) if you can create [a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) of the example data.

Answer (score 0):

to clarify a bit more i just added this:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61MMDBX4aRqtUFcwVk7Ujw/5#&togetherjs=oO3r8FlaAJ

it shows a simplified versione of my database structure (at the moment products with same MPN can have different click number, but i can keep them in sync)

this is a sample of frontend

https://www.puredesign.it/catalog/male-Scarpe/

my goal is to have multiple "ACQUISTA SU" button if the product can be found in more shop (i.e. same MPN on different product)